# Is there any length limitation of query string in ios phonegap?

Tags: string, cordova

Is there any length limitation of query string in ios phonegap?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Although the specification of the HTTP protocol does not specify any maximum length, practical limits are imposed by web browser and server software.

**Microsoft Internet Explorer (Browser)**

Microsoft states that the maximum length of a URL in **Internet Explorer** is 2,083 characters, with no more than 2,048 characters in the path portion of the URL. In my tests, attempts to use URLs longer than this produced a clear error message in Internet Explorer.

**Firefox (Browser)**

After 65,536 characters, the location bar no longer displays the URL in Windows Firefox 1.5.x. However, longer URLs will work. I stopped testing after 100,000 characters.

**Safari (Browser)**

At least 80,000 characters will work. I stopped testing after 80,000 characters.

**Opera (Browser)**

At least 190,000 characters will work. I stopped testing after 190,000 characters. Opera 9 for Windows continued to display a fully editable, copyable and pasteable URL in the location bar even at 190,000 characters.

**Apache (Server)**

My early attempts to measure the maximum URL length in web browsers bumped into a server URL length limit of approximately 4,000 characters, after which Apache produces a "413 Entity Too Large" error. I used the current up to date Apache build found in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 4. The official Apache documentation only mentions an 8,192-byte limit on an individual field in a request.

**Microsoft Internet Information Server**

The default limit is 16,384 characters (yes, Microsoft's web server accepts longer URLs than Microsoft's web browser). This is configurable.
**Perl HTTP::Daemon (Server)**

Up to 8,000 bytes will work. Those constructing web application servers with Perl's HTTP::Daemon module will encounter a 16,384 byte limit on the combined size of all HTTP request headers. This does not include POST-method form data, file uploads, etc., but it does include the URL. In practice this resulted in a 413 error when a URL was significantly longer than 8,000 characters. This limitation can be easily removed. Look for all occurrences of 16x1024 in Daemon.pm and replace them with a larger value. Of course, this does increase your exposure to denial of service attacks.

**Recommendations**

Extremely long URLs are usually a mistake. URLs over 2,000 characters will not work in the most popular web browser. Don't use them if you intend your site to work for the majority of Internet users.

References : http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html